# how does bash-script look to empty clipboard as daemon or cron-job?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

Am not sure if this is correct or can be done better. For any suggestion feel
free to post here. thx in advance.

Want to code a bash-script (Linux) which empties - after 30 days past by - the content of clipboard.

Have tried to simply pipe the content of clipboard to directory of /dev/zero - but this
does not work because "no permission" or "permission denied". How can I pipe into /dev/zero instead of using command rm ?

here the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]
do
find /usr/bin/xclip -selection "primary" -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm -- {} \;
done
return
```

while 1 with do and done will be substituted by code for daemon or cron-job.

The directory of clipboard in this snippet refers to Ubuntu.

Comment: What is the event from which on you start counting the thirty days?

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up `/dev/null` and `/dev/zero`.  The first is a sink to swallow everything you pipe in (and in case you read from it returns EOF at once), the other is a device outputting any number of zero bytes as long as you read from it.  You are not allowed to write to `/dev/zero` as it is only supposed to be read from.

For your task of emptying the X selection I propose this:

```
xclip < /dev/null
```

Comment: thx for answer. I tried that with /dev/null already too - and terminal spit out here too "permission denied" or "no permission".

Comment: I guess one should investigate which aspect causes that "permission denied" problem.  Does `cat /dev/null` also give an error message?  Does `: | xclip`?  What are the permission bits of `/dev/null`?  Are you sure your script file has the executable permission bit set?